# pip install pyqt5-tools error subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, pyqt5

im installing pyqt5 tools and this happens

```
C:\Users\Jansen>pip install pyqt5-tools
Collecting pyqt5-tools
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Downloading pyqt5_tools-5.15.3.3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Downloading pyqt5_tools-5.15.2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting python-dotenv
  Using cached python_dotenv-0.20.0-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.2
  Downloading PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 3.3/3.3 MB 6.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error`
```

im trying to install pyqt5 so that i can use the pyuic5 command

Comment: Is there nothing else ro the traceback? Do you have access to the toml

Comment: im sorry sir i 'm quite a newbie i don't actually know ro and toml

Comment: If you are using Python>=3.10, be aware that pyqt tools are not yet compatible, so you must downgrade to 3.9.

Comment: Oh ok im using python 3.10.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I can't yet comment questions, may I ask: are you using a virtual environment?
Anyway, you could try with this command:

```
pip install pyqt5-tools~=5.15
```

Moreover, as @musicamante said, if you're using a Python version that's above 3.10, a downgrade to version 3.9 or older is recommended as pyqt tools ar still not compatible with >3.9 versions. However, as I've seen [here](https://github.com/altendky/pyqt-tools/issues/98), you can try installing an specific 5.15 release version, so please try:

```
pip install PyQt5==5.15.5
```

Comment: i still have the same error

Comment: @JansenLloydMacabangun please, try again with the new suggested workaround.

Comment: thank you sir i tried to downgraded and successfully installed it

Answer (score 0):

1. Download python 3.9
2. Download virtualenv from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/virtualenv.pyz
3. Copy virtualenv.pyz to python 3.9 directory
4. Install virtualenv
   `python virtualenv.pyz env_folder`
5. Go to env_folder/Script.
6. Run activate file
7. pip install pyqt5-tools
8. Run Qt
   `pyqt5-tools designer`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, install the desired tool, in my case QT designer, i was not getting it installed with pyqt5-tools command, instead i used pip install pyqt5 designer, then the designer was not opening in terminal, then go to your python directory and find the name that designer has been assigned, in my case it was named only designer, then you can open the tool by giving the name in the directory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).